# How to change color of the stacked bar charts in amchart

Tags: jquery, charts, amcharts

I have started exploring AmCharts recently and was impressed by its superb features. However, I am trying to change the color of each stack in the bar but I haven`t been successful so far. I tried various properties like "balloonColor" to change the color of the respective stack but nothing happened.

Can someone let me know how can we do this?

This is the [graph](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-bar-chart/) I am taking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the bar's color by setting a particular graph's [`fillColors`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillColors) property, i.e.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "graphs": [{
      "fillColors": "#008800",
      "fillAlpha": 1, //must also be non-zero value; valid values are decimal values <= 1
       // ...
  },
  // repeat for each graph
  ],
  // ...
});
```

Here's a [modified version of the graph](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/876becad310e7f8ff09a4b7b35368b3b?editors=0010) that changes the Europe segment to green.

Comment: Spot on. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Amchart 4 chart color scheme can be set like so:

```
chart.colors.list = [
  am4core.color("#845EC2"),
  am4core.color("#D65DB1"),
  am4core.color("#FF6F91"),
  am4core.color("#FF9671"),
  am4core.color("#FFC75F"),
  am4core.color("#F9F871")
];
```

Amchart 4 piechart color scheme can be updated like this:

```
pieSeries.colors.list = [
  am4core.color("#845EC2"),
  am4core.color("#D65DB1"),
  am4core.color("#FF6F91"),
  am4core.color("#FF9671"),
  am4core.color("#FFC75F"),
  am4core.color("#F9F871"),
];
```

Documentation: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/colors/.  It also discusses gradients, etc.